# HP ProCurve 2910AL VLAN routing

Tags: routing, vlan, hp-procurve

Trying to add a VLAN to an existing network_

- Created VLAN 202 and named it Voice_New
- On VLAN 202 did IP Address 172.19.38.2 255.255.255.0
- in config, ensured IP Routing is enabled
- did IP Route 172.19.38.0 255.255.255.0 VLAN 202

However a show IP route does not show the route for the 172.19.38.0 subnet, and I cannot ping 172.19.38.2

What am I missing?

[image: Screen Grab]

Comment: `sh run` - please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route will not be added unless you connect a device to that VLAN. Routing tables don't show routes to links that are down.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a guru at HP Procurve switches. But I found at [VLAN routing help with e3800 and 2910al](https://community.hpe.com/t5/LAN-Routing/VLAN-routing-help-with-e3800-and-2910al/m-p/5617963#M543) that:

> Turns out having management enabled on VLAN1 was the problem. It won't route with management turned on.
>   Turned that off for vlan1 and all started working.

Also you must have got:

```
ip default-gateway X.X.X.X
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 X.X.X.X
ip routing
```

May be default gateway must be accessible via default vlan 1.